# Why is my ubuntu 14.04 connecting to my wifi network, but not actually connecting to the internet when i use Mozilla?

Tags: networking, wireless

As i said in the title, i recently installed ubuntu 14.0. My problem is that I can select my wifi network from the network manager, and according to the messages I get, it seems like it is connected to it. I get a message saying "connected to HOME_WIFI", but when I actually open my Mozilla browser, i can't connect to any website.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: First we should know if it is a DNS failure. post the output of the command `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping www.google.com`. If possible also the output of `ifconfig` and `route`commands.

Comment: Ping 8.8.8.8 causes my terminal to stall until i kill it (all packages lost), the same as ping 192.168.1.1

Comment: Ping www.google.com gets tje following output. "ping: unknown host www.google.com"

Comment: Ok. Please add to your question the ouptut of the command `route`.

Comment: Ok, as i type route, there are 8 columns: Destination, Gateway, Genmask, Flags, Metric, Ref, Use, Iface.

There are two entries:
Row1: default, 192.168.1.1,  0.0.0.0, UG, 0, 0, 0, wlan0
Row2: 192.168.1.0, *, 255.255.255.0, U, 9, 0, 0, wlan0

Comment: It's better and easier to read if you edit your question and you add the output in a good format. Anyway, I can't see nothing wrong, If you use cable, everything works?

Comment: Yes, if I use cable everything works.

Answer (score 1):

- open up your favorite terminal
- check if you got a ip address in the range of your local network

  `ifconfig`
- check if your gateway is set properly

  `route -n`

  The line starting with `Destination`: `0.0.0.0` needs ip address of your Router/Gateway under `Gateway`
- ping your gateway
- ping externel server (ex. google dns has ip `8.8.8.8`)
- check your DNS (for name resolution)

  `nm-tool | grep DNS`
- ping your DNS
- check if your DNS resolves
  (ex. `dig +short x.org @<ip-of-your-dns>`)
- if all is working well, check proxy settings of firefox and try to switch proxy off

Comment: When i run ifconfig, i see 3 different paragraphs. 

eth0, lo, wlan0. I guess wlan0 is the one for my wireless network, and the inet address there is 192.168.1.41

Comment: Like i mentioned in the upper answer, pinging my router causes to stall my terminal until i kill it (all packages lost).

When i run nm-tool | grep DNS i can see two addresses, both of them unreachable by ping just like my router's.

The last command "dig +short..." results in: 
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Maybe you have a firewall configured to block the traffic? What is the output of `sudo iptables -L`? And if you run ping command can you abort by typing [Ctrl - c] ?

Comment: @cybea I'd like to suggest that you use `ip addr show` instead of `ifconfig` and `ip route show` instead of `route -n` - to make your very good answer future proof.

Comment: What i get for sudo iptables -L:

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target   prot opt source   destination

Chain FORWARD (policy accept)
target   prot opt source    destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot opt source    destination

Nothing else